# Calculate difference scrore across factors in R

Tags: r, dataframe, difference

I have the following dataframe

```
    Class  Behavior   mean  
1     BH Baseline     5   
2     BH     Drnk     3   
3     BH      Lvr     2
4     BH     Tone     1
5     NB Baseline     6
6     NB     Drnk     3
7     NB      Lvr     2
```

I want to generate a new column where I have calculated the difference from baseline for each class and behavior so for example:

```
    Class  Behavior   mean  diff  
1     BH Baseline     5      0
2     BH     Drnk     3      2
3     BH      Lvr     2      3 
4     BH     Tone     1      4
5     NB Baseline     6      0
6     NB     Drnk     3      3
7     NB      Lvr     2      4
```

For each level of class, I want look at the difference between Baseline and all other Behaviors. I tried somethings using dplyr but I am just not sure how to make calculations across factor Baseline. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sample input

```
dd<-read.table(text="    Class  Behavior   mean  
1     BH Baseline     5   
2     BH     Drnk     3   
3     BH      Lvr     2
4     BH     Tone     1
5     NB Baseline     6
6     NB     Drnk     3
7     NB      Lvr     2", header=T)
```

You can get the desired output easily using `dplry`

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% group_by(Class) %>% 
    mutate(diff=mean[Behavior=="Baseline"]-mean)
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to load both `plyr` and `dplyr`. The order in which you load those matters. Make sure you load `plyr` first.